# Group collection by dates in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a collection with a field `datePublished`.

I have a template `postList` where I print a list with all the posts.

However, I need to group the posts by dates.

I need something like

```
Today
1. A
2. B

Yesterday
3. F
4. G

Friday
5. C

Thurday
6. D
```

In my helper, I am populating the template with `posts: function () { return Posts.find(); }` and in my template, I am simply printing them with

```
<ul>
  {{#each posts}}
    <li>{{title}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

but I don't know how it should look like if I have to group these posts by some dates.

## Edit

I just have multiple documents in my collection and each document has a date of which each document was published.

Instead of printing all the documents in a long list, I want to separate them into dates.

So first I will have to sort the list by the date, next I will have to group them, making

```
[ 
  { name: "A", date: "today" },
  { name: "B", date: "today" },
  { name: "C", date: "yesterday" },
  ...
]
```

into something like

```
[
  {
    today: [
      { name: "A" },
      { name: "B" }
    ]
  },
  {
    yesterday: [
      { name: "C" }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: adding to @ultrabowser 's questions, what have you tried?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: a few years late, but do you have a good solution for this?